Metric to track actual CPU usage
I've been a bit confused by the metrics available for monitoring CPU usage and what I'm looking for is to track actual CPU usage (not just increases) over time.
kube-state-metrics exposes a container_cpu_usage_seconds_total metric which is a cumulative value represented as core-seconds. So if the latest value is 0.7, it means I used 700 millicores of CPU usage for 1 second so far. Most implementations trying to track CPU usage then apply the rate function to this metric which gives you how much the usage increased per second. So if the initial value (for the specified interval) is 0.2, then the calculation is (0.7-0.2)/(seconds_passed) which tells me how much additional CPU I used on average per second. Is there a metric that just tells me what the absolute CPU usage at a moment in time is (similar to container_memory_working_set_bytes for memory)?
I feel like I am misunderstanding because most seem to be happy using a rate on the cumulative value, but it's not particularly helpful for me. For instance, when I see a service getting throttled, it would be great to know how high above the limit the CPU usage was. I'm also trying to look for services that are overprovisioned and having a metric showing the absolute usage over time would help so much. Thanks!
